# 12 V, 18 Ah battery for a solar panel

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, buck, solar-cell, amperage

I have a 100 W solar panel. I bought a 12 V, 18 Ah battery with a 30 A PWM solar  controller. How can I get this to charge right? The current will be too much for the battery. How can I cut down the current and and keep the voltage?

I'm thinking of buying another 18 Ah battery and parallel, series. Some kind of buck connections.

If it costs too much I will just buy another higher ampere battery. Could I also parallel this in? Will the bigger battery take the current so there will be less for the 18 Ah one?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144766/discussion-on-question-by-william-miller-12-v-18-ah-battery-for-a-solar-panel); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

A 100 W solar panel charging a nominally 12 V battery will deliver roughly 8.5 A, at most. At the end of the charging, this charging current will drop to about 7.5 A, at most. The solar panel will only deliver these currents under ideal circumstances under full sun.

If the battery is lead-acid, a good (but conservative) value for the charging current you want is 0.3 × capacity = 0.3 × 18 = 5.4 A.

For other battery types, you will have to look up the recommended charging current for your battery.

What really happens when you connect it all depends on the specifications of the "30 A PWM solar controller". The 30 A is the maximum current it can handle, not the current your battery will see (or your solar panel can deliver).

Check the recommended charging current for your battery in its documentation, and also the type/chemistry of the battery.

Then check if the solar controller is suitable for the battery type/chemistry and can be set/limited to the recommended charging current.

If the charging current can't be set/limited on the solar controller, and you want to be totally safe, then getting a bigger battery that can handle the maximum current the solar panel can deliver is the least wasteful solution (most solar energy harvested).

Comment: The battery I agm  glass mat and it says initial charging is 5.4 the controller will accommodate all battery types . I think it can be set to battery voltage has float cut off etc . But I think the max the battery will take atfull discharged which is initial is 5.4 and when it gets to half will be less . 2.5 . If the controller can set voltsvwill that set amps. I am thinking it will not . I just donot want to fry cells in battery or maybe catch it on fire . I need to know how to give it the charging amps it needs

Comment: I know if it was the other way around the battery could handle more amps then thepanal can pit out I would be fine . A car audio teq sorta since the 90s

Comment: @WilliamMiller this type of battery is unlikely to catch fire, but it may wear out much faster. In really bad situations (I don't think this one is really bad) it can also leak hydrogen gas. But mostly it just wears out faster.

Answer (score 1):

30 amps is the maximum that the controller will control before it breaks. The controller will not create the current. When the battery is low, the controller will let the solar panel charge the battery as fast as it can. When the battery is nearly full, the controller will limit the current, but it never creates more current.

The best solution is to get a different controller that allows you to choose a maximum current, so you can make it limit at 5.4A when the battery is empty and slow down to 2.5A when it is getting full.

Lead-acid batteries are pretty robust. It won't catch fire if you accidentally charge at 3.0A instead of 2.5A, and of course it's always okay to charge slower than recommended, so you don't have to get the curve exactly right.

If you can't get the right controller, I suppose the next best option is a smaller solar panel. This is not as good, because with a too-big solar panel and a current limit, you could still get more charging current in bad sunlight, than with a smaller panel.

You could fake a smaller panel by covering up some of your panel so it doesn't get sunlight, e.g. with duct tape. You have to cover part of each cell, not 100% of some of the cells, since the current is limited by the weakest cell. Technically I think you only have to cover part of one cell, but duct tape is cheap. Obviously you are now wasting a big part of the panel that you paid for.

Like I said, the best solution is to have a controller that could limit the current correctly - these other ideas are the not-so-good ideas.

As you said, you could add another battery in parallel. The charging current will be divided across all the batteries according to how easily they accept current (usually equally if they are the same size). If you do this you can use your whole panel and it's no longer too big for the battery pack because the battery pack is bigger. Of course, to do this, you have to buy another battery.

"technofreaks" suggested adding another current limiter (BMS) in the chain, but I don't think this will interact well with a PWM charge controller, which limits the current by turning the battery on and off quickly. One or the other might get confused by this and not work as expected.

Comment: Thanks . I was guessing right all along . Thinking I wasn't much of an electrician lol a duct man or refrigerant guy lol . I just got the solar panal today the controller will be here Friday as well as the battery . So I just will get a equivalent size and parallel it . I kinda rushed this and would gotten a bigger battery but had a 30 coupon so it was free being here in maryland April 18 is opening day of turkey season . Camping out for a week or so untill I get one . This is on my bucket list . THABKS AGAIN TO ALL  WHO HAS HELPED ME AND GAVE A PATRIOT SOME OF TGEIR PRECIOUS TIME . GOD BLESS